# What is a concise word or term for the cognitive ability to passively gather and recall personal minutiae about other people in one's life?

Tags: phrase-requests

Examples of the minutiae at issue are things like a person's hometown, the name(s) of their partner(s) and/or children, which, if any, college they attended, occupation, etc. Any piece of personal trivia that could come up in casual conversation.

A person who has this ability strongly might be able to intuit and then recall the name(s) and relative age(s) of a coworker's sibling(s) from a passing comment made years ago to a third party. One who has it weakly might require active study to learn and recall facts about their own spouse and/or children.

"Identity Memory" is a weak candidate that a) is too generic and b) does not seem to be in wide use. I will not reject it out of hand, however; I could be wrong about either or both of my objections to it.

Comment: If you were the person who downvoted my answer, would you mind telling me why?  Maybe I can improve it (or redo it completely).

Comment: The correct term is not "Identity Memory" but "eidetic Memory". This means remembering everything. Everyone posses it to some degree but those with phenomenal memory brag that only theirs is eidetic.

Comment: @Elliot Actually, eidetic means "relating to or denoting mental images having unusual vividness and detail, as if actually visible." [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/eidetic)].  Eidetic memory has more to do with "seeing" things in your mind rather than remembering facts.  Eidetic memory is also known as photographic memory.

Comment: @John Thank you. Photographic memory is very much myth. The eidetic memory is what people have and is the image of what has been seen. This has been discussed to death. Until one repeats and learns a fact by wrote it is the picture that sustains us.

Comment: @Elliot Do you mean "rote"?  Also, can you please check out my answer (if you haven't already) and let me know what you think?  Thanks!

Comment: @John Thanks for the spell check. Your answer looks to be thorough and complete.

Comment: @Elliot Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autobiographical_memory#:%7E:text=Biographical%20or%20Personal%3A%20These%20autobiographical%20memories%20often%20contain,a%20considerable%20amount%20of%20visual%20and%20sensory-perceptual%20detail.), there are four main categories of *autobiographical memory*, one of which is this:

> *Biographical or Personal*: These autobiographical memories often contain biographical information, such as where one was born or the names of one's parents.

On this basis, you might want to consider the term **biographical memory**, which would encompass a wide range of personal minutia about other people in one's life. From Lexico:

> **[biographical](https://www.lexico.com/definition/biographical)**: (of data or a written work) dealing with a particular person's life.

One's biographical memory could range anywhere from excellent to poor.

Answer (score 0):

**"Long-term memory," "explicit/declarative memory,"** or **"episodic memory"** can all be used to describe this.

*Note: "Long-term memory" is the only exoteric term in the list, whereas the other two are technical and should only be used with people who are knowledgeable in the field of psychology (or any related fields).*

---

In psychology, there are three main types of memory: sensory, short-term, and long-term.  In this case, we are talking about **long-term memory.**  One's long-term memory contains information that is *stored for more than a few moments.*

Within long-term memory, there are two more categories: explicit (declarative) and implicit (procedural) memory.  One's **explicit/declarative memory,** which is what we are talking about in this question, contains memories that are *consciously and intentionally* retained.

Within explicit/declarative memory, there are two more types: episodic and semantic memory.  In this case, we are talking about **episodic memory** because the facts that we are referring to  are *personally connected* to "person X."

Essentially the part of the "tree" of memory that we are looking at looks like this:

> Long-term —> Explicit/declarative —> Episodic

Therefore, you can use any of the three above terms when describing one's memory (in the context described by your question).

For example:

> Jim remembered my 2nd cousins name, which I told him five years ago!  He has such an incredible long-term memory.